# OneToMany associated objects don't load even with EAGER fetch mode

Tags: rest, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

Using Symfony 3.3.13 for an API

I have **LigneCommande** and **Commande** entities, where a *Commande* is linked to a *LigneCommande*.

**LigneCommande.php** has the following code:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;

/**
 * LigneCommande
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ligne_commande")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\LigneCommandeRepository")
 */
class LigneCommande
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @JMS\Groups({"listeLigneCommandes", "detailLigneCommande"})
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var Commande
     *
     * @JMS\Groups({"listeLigneCommandes", "detailLigneCommande"})
     *
     * Many LigneCommande have One numeroCommande.
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Commande", inversedBy="lignes", cascade={"all"}, fetch="EAGER")
     */
    protected $commande;

    /**
     * @var Article
     *
     * @JMS\Groups({"listeLigneCommandes", "detailLigneCommande"})
     *
     * Many LigneCommande have One codeArticle.
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="lignes", cascade={"all"}, fetch="EAGER")
     */
    protected $article;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @JMS\Groups({"listeLigneCommandes", "detailLigneCommande"})
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="libelle", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $libelle;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @JMS\Groups({"listeLigneCommandes", "detailLigneCommande"})
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="unite", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $unite;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @JMS\Groups({"listeLigneCommandes", "detailLigneCommande"})
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="qte_commande", type="float")
     */
    protected $qteCommande;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @JMS\Groups({"listeLigneCommandes", "detailLigneCommande"})
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="qte_recue", type="float")
     */
    protected $qteRecue;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @JMS\Groups({"listeLigneCommandes", "detailLigneCommande"})
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="qte_arecevoir", type="float")
     */
    protected $qteArecevoir;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @JMS\Groups({"listeLigneCommandes", "detailLigneCommande"})
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="identifiant", type="float", unique=true)
     */
    protected $identifiant;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set commande
     *
     * @param Commande $commande
     *
     * @return LigneCommande
     */
    public function setCommande(Commande $commande)
    {
        $this->numero = $commande;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get commande
     *
     * @return Commande
     */
    public function getCommande()
    {
        return $this->commande;
    }

    /**
     * Set article
     *
     * @param Article $article
     *
     * @return LigneCommande
     */
    public function setArticle(Article $article)
    {
        $this->article = $article;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get article
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function getArticle()
    {
        return $this->article;
    }

    /**
     * Set libelle
     *
     * @param string $libelle
     *
     * @return LigneCommande
     */
    public function setLibelle($libelle)
    {
        $this->libelle = $libelle;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get libelle
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLibelle()
    {
        return $this->libelle;
    }

    /**
     * Set unite
     *
     * @param string $unite
     *
     * @return LigneCommande
     */
    public function setUnite($unite)
    {
        $this->unite = $unite;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get unite
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUnite()
    {
        return $this->unite;
    }

    /**
     * Set qteCommande
     *
     * @param float $qteCommande
     *
     * @return LigneCommande
     */
    public function setQteCommande($qteCommande)
    {
        $this->qteCommande = $qteCommande;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get qteCommande
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getQteCommande()
    {
        return $this->qteCommande;
    }

    /**
     * Set qteRecue
     *
     * @param float $qteRecue
     *
     * @return LigneCommande
     */
    public function setQteRecue($qteRecue)
    {
        $this->qteRecue = $qteRecue;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get qteRecue
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getQteRecue()
    {
        return $this->qteRecue;
    }

    /**
     * Set qteArecevoir
     *
     * @param float $qteArecevoir
     *
     * @return LigneCommande
     */
    public function setQteArecevoir($qteArecevoir)
    {
        $this->qteArecevoir = $qteArecevoir;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get qteArecevoir
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getQteArecevoir()
    {
        return $this->qteArecevoir;
    }

    /**
     * Set identifiant
     *
     * @param float $identifiant
     *
     * @return LigneCommande
     */
    public function setIdentifiant($identifiant)
    {
        $this->identifiant = $identifiant;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get identifiant
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getIdentifiant()
    {
        return $this->identifiant;
    }
}
```

**Commande.php** has the following code:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;

/**
 * Commande
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="commande")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CommandeRepository")
 */
class Commande
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @JMS\Groups({"listeCommandes"})
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @JMS\Groups({"listeCommandes", "detailCommande"})
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="numero", type="string", length=8, unique=true)
     */
    private $numero;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @JMS\Groups({"listeCommandes", "detailCommande"})
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="date")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @JMS\Groups({"listeCommandes", "detailCommande"})
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="chantier_id", type="integer")
     *
     * Many Commande have One chantierCode.
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Chantier")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="chantier_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $chantier;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @JMS\Groups({"listeCommandes", "detailCommande"})
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fournisseur_code", type="string", length=7)
     */
    private $fournisseurCode;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @JMS\Groups({"listeCommandes", "detailCommande"})
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fournisseur_nom", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $fournisseurNom;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @JMS\Groups({"listeCommandes", "detailCommande"})
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="redacteur_code", type="string", length=5)
     */
    private $redacteurCode;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @JMS\Groups({"listeCommandes", "detailCommande"})
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="secteur_code", type="string", length=1, nullable=true)
     */
    private $secteurCode;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @JMS\Groups({"listeCommandes", "detailCommande"})
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="livraison_nom", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $livraisonNom;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @JMS\Groups({"listeCommandes", "detailCommande"})
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="livraison_adresse", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $livraisonAdresse;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @JMS\Groups({"listeCommandes", "detailCommande"})
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="livraison_cp", type="string", length=5)
     */
    private $livraisonCp;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @JMS\Groups({"listeCommandes", "detailCommande"})
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="livraison_ville", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $livraisonVille;

    /**
     * @var Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="LigneCommande", mappedBy="commande")
     */
    protected $lignes;


    public function __construct() {
        $this->lignes = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set numero
     *
     * @param string $numero
     *
     * @return Commande
     */
    public function setNumero($numero)
    {
        $this->numero = $numero;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get numero
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNumero()
    {
        return $this->numero;
    }

    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     *
     * @return Commande
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * Set chantier
     *
     * @param int $chantier
     *
     * @return Commande
     */
    public function setChantier($chantier)
    {
        $this->chantier = $chantier;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get chantier
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getChantier()
    {
        return $this->chantier;
    }

    /**
     * Set fournisseurCode
     *
     * @param string $fournisseurCode
     *
     * @return Commande
     */
    public function setFournisseurCode($fournisseurCode)
    {
        $this->fournisseurCode = $fournisseurCode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fournisseurCode
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFournisseurCode()
    {
        return $this->fournisseurCode;
    }

    /**
     * Set fournisseurNom
     *
     * @param string $fournisseurNom
     *
     * @return Commande
     */
    public function setFournisseurNom($fournisseurNom)
    {
        $this->fournisseurNom = $fournisseurNom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fournisseurNom
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFournisseurNom()
    {
        return $this->fournisseurNom;
    }

    /**
     * Set redacteurCode
     *
     * @param string $redacteurCode
     *
     * @return Commande
     */
    public function setRedacteurCode($redacteurCode)
    {
        $this->redacteurCode = $redacteurCode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get redacteurCode
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRedacteurCode()
    {
        return $this->redacteurCode;
    }

    /**
     * Set secteurCode
     *
     * @param string $secteurCode
     *
     * @return Commande
     */
    public function setSecteurCode($secteurCode)
    {
        $this->secteurCode = $secteurCode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get secteurCode
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSecteurCode()
    {
        return $this->secteurCode;
    }

    /**
     * Set livraisonNom
     *
     * @param string $livraisonNom
     *
     * @return Commande
     */
    public function setLivraisonNom($livraisonNom)
    {
        $this->livraisonNom = $livraisonNom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get livraisonNom
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLivraisonNom()
    {
        return $this->livraisonNom;
    }

    /**
     * Set livraisonAdresse
     *
     * @param string $livraisonAdresse
     *
     * @return Commande
     */
    public function setLivraisonAdresse($livraisonAdresse)
    {
        $this->livraisonAdresse = $livraisonAdresse;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get livraisonAdresse
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLivraisonAdresse()
    {
        return $this->livraisonAdresse;
    }

    /**
     * Set livraisonCp
     *
     * @param string $livraisonCp
     *
     * @return Commande
     */
    public function setLivraisonCp($livraisonCp)
    {
        $this->livraisonCp = $livraisonCp;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get livraisonCp
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLivraisonCp()
    {
        return $this->livraisonCp;
    }

    /**
     * Set livraisonVille
     *
     * @param string $livraisonVille
     *
     * @return Commande
     */
    public function setLivraisonVille($livraisonVille)
    {
        $this->livraisonVille = $livraisonVille;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get livraisonVille
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLivraisonVille()
    {
        return $this->livraisonVille;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getLignes() {
        return $this->lignes;
    }
}
```

**LigneCommandeController.php** has the following code:

```
/**
     * @Rest\View(serializerGroups={"detailLigneCommande"})
     * @Rest\Get(
     *     path = "/ligneCommandes/{id}",
     *     name = "show_ligne_commande",
     *     requirements = {"id"="\d+"}
     * )
     */
    public function getLigneCommandeAction(Request $request)
    {
        $ligneCommande = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:LigneCommande')
            ->find($request->get('id'));
        /* @var $ligneCommande LigneCommande */

        $ligneCommande->getCommande();

        if (empty($ligneCommande)) {
            return View::create(['message' => 'Ligne de commande introuvable'], Response::HTTP_OK);
        } else {
            return $ligneCommande;
        }
    }
```

So in my API when I call `localhost:8000/ligneCommandes/1` with the fetch 'EAGER' attribute I hope get something like that :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "commande": {
        "numero": "CF000001",
        "date": "2017-10-13T00:00:00+00:00",
        "chantier": 1,
        "fournisseur_code": "F000001",
        "fournisseur_nom": "Fournisseur A",
        "redacteur_code": "FTOMA",
        "secteur_code": "1",
        "livraison_nom": "Nom livraison",
        "livraison_adresse": "Adresse livraison",
        "livraison_cp": "74940",
        "livraison_ville": "Ville livraison"
    },
    "article": {},
    "libelle": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
    "unite": "TL",
    "qte_commande": 10,
    "qte_recue": 8,
    "qte_arecevoir": 2,
    "identifiant": 1
}
```

But I get this :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "commande": {},
    "article": {},
    "libelle": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
    "unite": "TL",
    "qte_commande": 10,
    "qte_recue": 8,
    "qte_arecevoir": 2,
    "identifiant": 1
}
```

I don't really know why, even with the fetch EAGER method, the object still load as proxy.

Thanks you for your help :)

Comment: Are you sure that is an ORM problem? It could be your serializer that is not processing child entities. In the past this happened to me using serialization groups, so I moved to Fractal in order to have more control over the serialization process.

Comment: It's not a bad idea ! In addition I realize that when I dump my element before serialize, the chils entities are there. I will look into it ;) Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution.
Just remove the serializer groups and it's works.